# ¿como capturar evento de teclado en aplicacion de consola en java?

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una aplicacion que simula el juego del tetris en la consola. Necesito capturar los eventos del teclado (en concreto las flechas) para poder mover la pieza a la izquierda y derecha.
este es el codigo del main:

```
public class tetris {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        areaDeJuego area=new areaDeJuego();

        while(true)
        {
            area.mostrar();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(450);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            if(!area.llegoAlFondo() && !area.getPiezaEnJuego().tropezoConOtraPieza())
            {
                area.moverAbajo();
            }
            
            else
            {
                area.depositarPieza(area.getPiezaEnJuego());
                area.nuevaPieza();
            }           
        }               
    }
}
```

Ahora solo me falta capturar los eventos del teclado.

Comment: ¿Has probado con un KeyListener? Puedes indicar una tecla con keyPressed(KeyEvent e), así al presionarla realiza dicho evento.

Comment: he probado pero parece ser que en aplicaciones de consola no va. En la consola de windows me refiero.